# Is an SQL Injection possible if input is only treated as a string?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

Question is in the title, but code example found below:

HTML:

```
<form name="input" action="demo_form_action.asp" method="post">
  Username: <input type="text" name="user">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$data['userName'] = $_POST['user'];

$query = "INSERT INTO Persons (value1) VALUES ('$data['userName']')";
mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

So basically I populate part of an array with the input and then that value gets put in a DB table somewhere. To clarify I am using Drupal 7 - and later on in the code this is done:

```
node_save($data);
```

But all this seems to do is copy the string into the DB. I am interested in how Drupal 7 will treat this, but also ask in a custom environment:

If a variable that is passed from a form is NOT used as part of an SQL Query and simply written to the DB as a string is there still a chance of an SQL injection attack?

Of course - this does not include reading the string at a later date and then using it as part of a query. And after having written all this I think - well the string has to be inserted using a query anyway, so as long as the attacker knows the format of the query used they would be able to write a string that manipulates it to perform an injection attack (without any data sanitization, of course)...sorry if the initial question sounds stupid - I haven't done this long, just thought I would throw it out there.

Thanks, and much obliged!

Comment: `'; DROP TABLE Persons; #`

Comment: you're stuffing that 'external' data INTO a string, which means PHP will convert whatever that data is into a string itself. By definition, **ANY** data getting stuffed into a query string can be used as an injection attack vector. it may not be practical, it may not be easy, but if it's coming from the outside, you have to treat it as highly toxic waste. That also means any data you yourself created can also cause an injection attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of SQL injection is that a query like:

```
INSERT INTO Persons (value1) VALUES ('$data['userName']')
```

is vulnerable to the user submitting a username like this:

```
something'); DROP TABLE Persons; SELECT 1=('1
```

resulting in the following query being executed:

```
INSERT INTO Persons (value1) VALUES ('something'); DROP TABLE Persons; SELECT 1=('1');
```

Goodbye, Persons table! `DROP TABLE` isn't the only risk, either. It could, for example, be used to bypass checking a user's password against the database, to spit out sensitive data, etc.

Answer (score 3):

> But all this seems to do is copy the string into the DB.

That does not simply "copy the string into the DB".

That uses the string in some executable code and then tells the database server to execute that code.

It is entirely vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Yes...this is true - I corrected myself while typing - then clicked publish... :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not really understanding the nature of how SQL injection attack works.  When your concatenate that variable into your SQL query string, unless you have escaped it to prevent injection, it is vulnerable, as that resulting concatenated string IS the command executed by the database.

You should strongly consider using parametrized prepared statements for such DB access.